# SQL Server Management Studio 2012 doesn't allow single quotation typing

Tags: sql-server, ssms

If I type text in SQL Server Management Studio then it doesn't repond when I type the single <kbd>'</kbd> character. If I type it twice however then it shows me both next to each other e.g.

> ''

Since strings in queries are identified with single quotes it is really frustrating having to press twice <kbd>'</kbd> and then use backspace to get single quote.

Also if I type <kbd>'</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> for example it shows as

> Á

This problem started about two weeks ago. It was never a problem before

Comment: Nothing wrong with SSMS 2012, which came out 5 years ago. If a problem appeared two weeks ago it's because something changed on the machine - a new program was added perhaps, that captures keystrokes? Or you added a new keyboard layout?

Comment: BTW SSMS is a *separate* downloadable product now. Its latest version is 17.3 which came out about a month ago.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has nothing to do with SSMS. Check your language preferences in Windows.

Usually quotes work like that with British layout, change it to EN US.

This answer on Super User is useful and will solve your problem: https://superuser.com/questions/346142/my-windows-keyboard-is-being-clever-with-the-quote-keys-how-can-i-stop-it

Comment: Thanks I noticed it is keyboard layout. It was set as English International. I switched it back to English US and the problem dissapeared.